# Indexing of original vector in a function in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I want to write a function in VHDL which is given the top few bits of a `std_logic_vector` and does stuff to them but it seems to be that the indexing of my function still starts counting at the bottom of the whole vector.

I can get around this by first assigning my vector to a temporary signal and using that but I'm worried that I don't understand what's going on here.

Could someone explain why `a` and `b` don't get the same output in the below?

```
architecture rtl of inds is
  function top_bit (c : std_logic_vector) return std_logic is
  begin
    return c(c'length-1);
  end top_bit;
  signal temp : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
begin
  temp <= input(3 downto 1);
  a <= top_bit(temp);
  b <= top_bit(input(3 downto 1));
end rtl;
```

If you give them the input `"0100"`, you get `a='0', b='1'`.

If you give them the input `"1000"`, you get `a='1', b='0'`.

So `a=temp(2)=input(3)` and `b=input(2)` which is `input("length of c" -1)`.

I don't think this makes sense, can someone justify it for me.

**Edit:** if you replace the declaration line with:

```
function top_bit (c : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0)) return std_logic is
```

then it works as I'd expect. 
I suppose the vector `c` takes it's indexing from the vector it's given.

I'd like to see a function which takes an arbitrary slice of a vector and returns the top bit of that slice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `'length` attribute, where you could be using `'high`. I think this would do what you're asking for.

I've got a print out on my wall of the table here http://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/attribute.html as a reference for what attributes are available.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about that. I forget you can have vectors which aren't numbered `x downto 0`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue, is that `c'length` returns the length of the vector which is not necessarily a valid index.  For example, say I declared the following signal:

```
signal temp : std_logic_vector(7 downto 4);
```

This would cause a range error calling `top_bit`.  As you note in your comment on scary_jeff's answer, not all vectors are `x downto 0`.  They could be `x downto y`.  Or they could even by `0 to x` or `x to y`.  Assuming that `c'length-1` is the top bit is only true if `c` is declared as `std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0)` (which you discovered in your answer).

Just as a clarification.  scary_jeff's answer is the correct way.  However, you need to resolve what is meant by "top_bit".  What if you are given a `to` vector, such as:

```
signal temp : std_logic_vector(4 to 7)
```

What is top bit?  Bit 4 or bit 7?  If you use `'high`, you'll get bit 7.  Is this the top bit?  If you want bit 4 to be the top bit, you'll need to use `'low`.